# Git save password of remote connection locally, connecting via root@

Tags: linux, git, centos

I would just like to start by saying I am completely new to git so I am probably doing things the wrong way but am trying to follow posts on here and guides online. I know this is probably a dumb post, but I am just a web designer so very basic with this stuff, would appreciate any advice about the way I am doing this, or if there is a better way.

I installed git on my centos vps and then setup my repository inside my website, location here:

`/var/www/vhosts/server.userfarmer.com/userfarmer/userfarmer.git`

The userfarmer folder before the .git folder is my main websites directory, I am trying to upload my website from my local machines via git to this folder. I set this up over ssh using:

```
mkdir userfarmer.git
cd userfarmer.git
git --bare init
```

I have then setup the git remote connection locally using:

`git remote add origin root@serverip:/var/www/vhosts/server.userfarmer.com/userfarmer/userfarmer.git`

now I can connect to this fine but each time I do I require my root password, is there anyway to save this so it is not needed each time I do a push.

Any advice greatly appreciated, this is all completly new to me,
Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Have you tried adding your public ssh key `ssh.key.pub` to the `authorized_keys` file on your server?

Comment: I have generated an ssh key locally called "laptop.pub" however I am unsure on how I go about adding it onto the server. or even finding the location for it on the server, sorry I am still learning as I go along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your server create a .ssh folder at root user home directory.

```
mkdir /root/.ssh/
```

Give it 700 permission.

```
chmod 7000 /root/.ssh/
```

Create a file named "authorized_keys" inside the .ssh folder and give it permission 600

```
touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /root.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now from your laptop:

Append your public key i.e loptop.pub content to authorized_keys.

```
cat ~/.ssh/laptop.pub | ssh root@serverip "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can open the file

.git/config

look for line

url=root@serverip:/var/www/vhosts/server.userfarmer.com/userfarmer/userfarmer.git

and add your password in format:

url=root:**password**@serverip:/var/www/vhosts/server.userfarmer.com/userfarmer/userfarmer.git

next time you open a repo, add it by writing

git remote add origin root:password@serverip:/var/www/vhosts/server.userfarmer.com/userfarmer/userfarmer.git